# How to specify comma , space unicode value in app.config(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

In the app.config file if I use 
`<add key = "FileDelimeter" value ="&#2c;"/>` as unicode for **COMMA**, it is throwing error

**Invalid character in a decimal number 'c'**

For **SPACE**, `<add key = "FileDelimeter" value ="&#20;"/>` the error is

> Character'', hex value 0*14 is illegal
>   in xml

while `<add key = "FileDelimeter" value ="&#09;"/>` for "**\t"** worked.

Where is the mistake?

Kindly give a generic solution.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I could not get u properly...

Comment: `<add key = "FileDelimeter" value =","/>`
Doesn't this work, in case of comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&#` prefix denotes a decimal (base 10) number. Try using `&#x` (the 'x' is for He**x**adecimal) as the prefix:

```
<add key = "FileDelimeter" value ="&#x2C;"/>
```